# what does "-v" mean in "git branch test_branch -v 7cd3aa021"

Tags: git

It seems like `git branch test_branch -v 7cd3aa021` means create a new branch from revision `7cd3aa021`.

I don't know what does "-v" mean here. I tried to read `git branch --help` but I think the explain there isn't the same "-v" with this situation.

Comment: What makes you doubt the documentation? Are you seeing something you aren't expecting?

Comment: At first time I thought if I want to create a branch from a specific revision I have to use `-v 7cd3aa021 `, so maybe `-v` means give the specific revision. But after that I have tried create branch by using `git branch test_branch 7cd3aa021`, it can also create the branch in 7cd3aa021. There is no doubt now ... :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When in list mode, show sha1 and commit subject line for each head, along with relationship to upstream branch (if any). If given twice, print the name of the upstream branch, as well (see also git remote show ).

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch